# Dual listbox - how to move items between two list-boxes?

Tags: jquery, listbox

Do you know any jquery plugin or something to implement dual list-boxes?

I searched and found this project http://kgaddy.com/jqueryMoverBoxes/ but the it is very simple.

Comment: Provided link is dead. All the links on this page are all dead.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.billsternberger.net/jquery/how-to-create-a-dual-listbox-in-jquery/

Hope this helps.

Comment: It appears that this link is dead.

Comment: I think since that day there are much more information on google than there was at the time. Searching for "dual listbox in jquery" I could find, at least, these two: http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/  and  http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multi-Select-List-Box-Plugin-listbox-js.html    Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by **Gabriel Oliveira** is a nice and short example of how to implement dual listboxes with jquery and Microsoft .NET MVC (although MVC isn't required). But just in case someone else get to this question here is another JQuery plug-in option http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx

Comment: Turns out your link is dead too.