# html fulfill a table using a list

Tags: html, forms, list

I know this seems to be a joke but I'm looking for something that I can not find, because I do not know how it is called.

In fact it is using forms

we have a list in which we can save our choice to an other list.

And if we want we can remove this choice.

I don't know how it is called and how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand a thing. Do you have some code? A screenshot?

Comment: it looks like something like this http://progeris.comyr.com/list.png I have no code because I don't know how it is called or how is it made

Comment: in what context you are asking want to move it in html or array or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to move elements from one list to another? That is what I understand from your request.

There are some questions on this site that tackle the same problem, like : [Dual listbox - how to move items between two list-boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451246/dual-listbox-move-items-between-tow-list-boxes)

Good luck!